# Zend Framework with ZFDebug, how to get the db adapter

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following in my application.ini file

`resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"`
`resources.db.params.host = "localhost"`
`resources.db.params.username = ".."`
`resources.db.params.password = ".."`
`resources.db.params.dbname = "lsc3_base"`
`resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true`

Now this works perfectly and I can query the database no problem.

Im trying to install ZFDebug which also was easy using the following in my main bootstrap.php file

`   protected function _initZFDebug()
    {
        $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        $autoloader->registerNamespace('ZFDebug');

```
    $options = array(
        'plugins' => array('Variables', 
            'Time',
            #'Auth',
            'Memory',
            'Registry', 
            'Database' => array('adapter' => $db), 
            'File' => array('basePath' => '/path/to/project'),
            #'Cache' => array('backend' => $cache->getBackend()), 
            'Exception')
    );
    $debug = new ZFDebug_Controller_Plugin_Debug($options);

    $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    $frontController = $this->getResource('frontController');
    $frontController->registerPlugin($debug);
}
```

`
Now this obviously gives me a notice saying $db undefined.

Question is how do I get hold of $db?

I have tried the following:
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$db = $this->getPluginResource('db');

Which I am assuming dont work because its connecting to the database AFTER doing all of the things in my bootstrap. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

This should help, make a $db variable like this:

```
$this->bootstrap('db');
$db = $this->getPluginResource('db')->getDbAdapter();
```